# Solr 6.1.0 loses cores after restart

Tags: solr, jetty

I installed a new solr instance for testing. I used this documentation: [Take solr to production](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Taking+Solr+to+Production)
It's working fine but on restart I'm losing all cores. They are not deleted but on start solr does not find them.
Any idea what is wrong?

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely restarting Solr with a wrong **solr home**, as discussed in the document you linked to.

You can check the core location in the [Admin UI's Overview screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Core-Specific+Tools) for that core. Your home is above that location, where solr.xml file lives. Or you can look for the **solr.solr.home** variable in [the Java Properties screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Java+Properties).

Comment: Thanks a lot. My solr home dir is /var/solr61test/data and I tried to add a core searchPL whit data dir and conf dir inside. Before restart it's looks ok but after, the core is missing. Is it because it's not a multicore installation?

Comment: I found the problem. The core.properties file was not created automatically. After I created manually it's working fine. But I don't know the reason for that. Thanks again.

Comment: I would check the user Solr runs under vs. the directory owner and access flags. Sounds like the permission issue on your system.

Comment: Yes, you are right, after I post the comment I just realized what was the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

check 
/opt/solr/server/solr/solr.xml
or
/var/solr/data/solr.xml

update coreRootDirectory

```
<solr>
    <str name="coreRootDirectory">/path/to/solr/data/</str>
    <solrcloud>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by restarting the service